# Running ant commands using batch file

Tags: batch-file, ant

Currently this is how I have written the code in the batch file:

```
C:\ cd C:\abc\xyz\build-scripts-master
call setEnv.cmd
cmd ant do-clean
cmd ant do-dist
```

This is not working. It just executes the `setEnv` and breaks out. It does not run the remaining commands

Manually this is how it works:

- I first go to the folder `C:\abc\xyz\build-scripts-master` through the Command Prompt
- Then I type in `setEnv`, which is a windows command script, and hit return.
- Then I type in `ant do-clean`
- And then `ant do-dist`

I want to automate this process and hence was trying to achieve this using batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```bat
@CD /D "C:\abc\xyz\build-scripts-master"
@Call setEnv.cmd
@Call ant.bat do-clean
@Call ant.bat do-dist
```

The latter two lines assume that `ant.bat` is located somewhere in the current working directory or `%PATH%`

*It is not imperative that the directory path is doublequoted in this case, just good practice.
You could continue not to use the `.bat` extension with `ant`. I've included it just to make it clear that it is a batch file, and should be `Call`ed in the same way as the `setEnv` batch file.*

Answer (score 0):

it didn't run the bat files because you didn't specify the files' location in the code.  As it stands right now, the script expects the .bats to exist in the working directory or it has been placed in the folder.    The only way it will run the files arbitrarily is if you had placed your working location in the system variables or set the Path to the folders location.  I don't know if the cmd and call are needed.  I have never used them in my scripts.

Comment: An answer has already been provided and accepted, and because this is not an answer, _just a comment_, please delete it.